How to run smartgit on Windows 11 ARM based laptop?
I was able to install smartgit using its portable installer on an ARM Windows 11 laptop. When I double click smartgit.exe, nothing pops up.
Wondering if there is a way to get this tool running natively on ARM.
The version of smartgit: 21.2.4

The Provided Version of Smartgit doesn't work. Install the latest version for compatibility.

What is the earliest version of smartgit that added support for ARM? If that version falls under supported versions for my license, I can skip the upgrade cost.
